# Copy files from a set of folders on one server to same set of folders on another server C#

Tags: c#, file, copy

I have a list (list1) with the file names:

```
C:\\Work\\Server1\\CSRegWeb\\Transform\\Faq.xslt
C:\\Work\\Server1\\CSRegWeb\\Content\\Axxess.xml
C:\\Work\\Server1\\CSRegWeb\\kleenex.aspx
C:\\Work\\Server1\\CSRegWeb\\Content\\dell.xml
```

I need to copy these files to another server (with the same folder structure), which is called server2. So the folder locations are:

```
C:\\Work\\Server2\\CSRegWeb\\Transform\\Faq.xslt
C:\\Work\\Server2\\CSRegWeb\\Content\\Axxess.xml
C:\\Work\\Server2\\CSRegWeb\\kleenex.aspx
C:\\Work\\Server2\\CSRegWeb\\Content\\dell.xml
```

I need to copy over the files (which can be copy or overwrite).
(For now they are server1 & server2, the server names can change).
Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code I have:

```
DESTINATION_PROJECT_ROOT = "C:\\Work\\Server2"
projectName = "CSRegWeb"

string dest = DESTINATION_PROJECT_ROOT + "\\" + projectName + "\\" ;
foreach (FileInfo k in List1)
{
    foreach (FileInfo j in List2)
    {
        if (k.Name == j.Name && k.Directory.Name == j.Directory.Name)
        {
             File.Copy(k.FullName, dest , true);
             break;
        }
    }
}
```

This only replaces the modified files.

Comment: @Jon, Sorry I forgot to post the code, I just pasted the code I had

Comment: DESTINATION_PROJECT_ROOT gives the server location, which we get from the app.config file

Comment: @superstar: Do you only **want** to copy over files that already exist? If there are new files, those will not be copied over.

Comment: @jp2code: the above code did what you said, so I modified it now, to handle the new files as well. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can access it that way. Try it this way instead:

```
string path = @"\\Server2\CSRegWeb\Transform\Faq.xslt";
```

**EDIT**

Or if you're storing it in web.config, try this:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="CopyToLocation" value="\\Server2" />    
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the destination path to something like what I suggested?

Comment: but i cant hard-code the server name, it is subject to change

Comment: So how is the application supposed to know which server to copy the files to? Putting the above string in your app.config is one option...

Comment: that is what I am doing now, getting the server from app.config

Comment: So what's the problem?? Is the path you're using not working?

Comment: i only get the server name from app.config, the file names are from list1 which needs to be copied...